# API Gateway: Error during configuring API mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I created a wildcard certificate `*.example.com` on ACM in my region.
Then I add `subdomain.example.com` to my custom domain names on API Gateway. The subdomain was configured correctly (it did not give me an error).

When I try to configure mappings of API I get the error `Unable to complete operation due to concurrent modification. Please try again later.`

I have tried it multiple times. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you use CloudFormation for that, it fails in the console?

Comment: @Marcin used it through the console. Sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is probably with API gateway UI console(AWS Management Console).
When I tried creating the mapping from the AWS CLI, it worked.
I used the `aws apigateway create-base-path-mapping` command.

Details on the API are at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/create-base-path-mapping.html